# Fancyselect: How to force to open the selector at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

**This is the plugin:**

Fancyselect page -   http://code.octopuscreative.com/fancyselect/

**This is the situation:**

I need to control the position where the selector window with the various options is going to open.

I have tried to look into the code, but i did not figured out how to do it.
But i think that, by default, it depends if there is or not some space above.

To be more clear I have recreated two examples:

Here the selector is opening at the top:   http://jsbin.com/AqoYucAG/2/edit

Here the selector is opening at the bottom:  http://jsbin.com/AqoYucAG/3/edit

But, trust me, the css and the js are exactly the same in the both.
What change is that in the second example it misses the div with its content.

My actual situation is similar to the first example: the fancyselect is under a div with some text, and as in the jsbin, the selector is opening at the top, while i need to open it at the bottom.

**This is the question:**

How is possible to control the position where the selector is going to open?
And how to make it opening at the bottom?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if ((parent.offset().top + parent.outerHeight() + options.outerHeight() + 20) > $(window).height()) {
            options.addClass('overflowing');
          } else {
            options.removeClass('overflowing');
          }
        }
```

he add and remove overflowing class 
that css class control the way control is opened

if add > `options.addClass('overflowing');` 
the select will open at the bottom

to test that try to comment `//options.addClass('overflowing');` and see the behavior

Comment: I have tried your solutions both on my project and on the jsbin but is not working in both.

Comment: this one at top  http://jsbin.com/AqoYucAG/3/edit
comment options.addClass('overflowing');
and see the result